# For every option different selection [formControl]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to implement a button that creates a mat-form-field

```js
days = new FormControl();
daysList: string[] = ['Monday', 'Thuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];


openExecutionTimeScheduler() {
  let now = new Date();

  this.weekDayAndTime.weekDay = []

  var weekday = new Array(7);
  weekday[0] = "Sunday";
  weekday[1] = "Monday";
  weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
  weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
  weekday[4] = "Thursday";
  weekday[5] = "Friday";
  weekday[6] = "Saturday";
  this.weekDayAndTime.weekDay.push(weekday[now.getDay()])
  this.days.setValue(this.weekDayAndTime.weekDay)
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row" class="m-portlet__body" *ngFor="let time of times; let i = index;">

  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Days Of Week</mat-label>
    <mat-select [formControl]="days" multiple>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let day of daysList" [value]="day">{{day}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

when i create a new item, it overrides the already selected fields and sets the week day to today's week day. How do make the items independent from each other? So if i create an mat-form-field it pre-selects today as default day and if i choose another day, it doesn't override the previous mat-form-fields

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray).

Example

```html
<ng-container formArrayName="days">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let daysForm of days.controls; let i = index">
      <div class="days-form-row" [formGroup]="daysForm">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Days Of Week</mat-label>
          <mat-select [formControl]="weekday" multiple>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let day of daysList" [value]="day">{{day}}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Form Setup

```ts
form = this.fb.group({
  // other form controls,
  days: this.fb.array([])
});

constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {}

get days() {
  return this.form.controls["days"] as FormArray;
}
```

Add Lesson

```ts
addDayControl() {
  const dayForm = this.fb.group({
    weekday: ['Sunday', Validators.required]
  });
  this.days.push(dayForm);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! When i use your code, i get the following error: Error: formArrayName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
       directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class). Here is a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4rvjkd?file=src/app/app.component.ts. How could i solve it?

Comment: wrap it in `<div class="add-days-form" [formGroup]="form">` For more details read: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-form-array/